# How to create a variable sized float type array in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need a float type array; don't know the size of array initially. When I will get the value of size, I want to add some float values in it by a for loop. This array need to be global because I want to update it from another view controller class. How can I do this?

For this I declared a NSMutableArray type object and add float value by a for loop.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray   *speedRate;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.assetArray.count; i++){
   [self.speedRate addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
    }

NSLog(@"speedRate.count =%lu",(unsigned long)self.speedRate.count);
NSLog(@"value =%f",[[self.speedRate objectAtIndex:1]floatValue]);
```

But I got speedRate.count =0 and value =0.000 . I want speedRate.count will be same as self.assetArray.count and value =1.0 . How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code never actually allocates the array. Add

```
self.speedRate = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

before the loop.

Comment: I am greatful for your response. It works but I am facing another problem now. I am trying to update self.speedRate like "self.speedRate[position] = rate;" . But getting an error like " Sending 'float' to parameter of incompatible type 'id _Nonnull' " . Can you help me about this?

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question

Comment: If rate is a float, it is not an object. An NSArray can only contain objects. Try `@(rate)` which will make it an NSNumber object.